# SOQL: Performing Query with both LIKE & IN

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have a list of accounts that I would like to perform a LIKE query on. Ideally, my query would be something like:

```
SELECT id, owner.name FROM Account WHERE name LIKE IN :entityList
```

Is there any way I can do this?

The issue is that my entity names come from a third party source, which means that small variations in name may be present, i.e

> "Bay Ridge apt."   VS   "Bay Ridge Apartments"

It's hard to predict where the difference in spelling might be, and I was hoping that the LIKE filter might be some magical filter that can figure this out for me and match on a substring (i.e. "Bay Ridge").

How can I perform this query?

Thank you!

EDIT: The Salesforce guide doesn't include this option in their guide, so it might not be possible to combine a LIKE and an IN. Maybe there's a solution around it?
[SOQL Comparison Operators](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm)

EDIT: Maybe there's a way to perform a SOSL query on a list? Something like :

```
Find {entityList} In Account
```

I can't seem to find this any where...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this through looping and make dynamic query depend upon your list.

```
String[]  entityList = new String []{'CEO','CFO','CMO','CTO','CIO','COO','VP','DIRECTOR','VIP'};

Boolean first = true;
query = 'Select Id FROM CONTACT';
for(String el : entityList){
    if(!first){
        query += ' OR';
    } else {
        query += ' WHERE';
    }
    query = query + ' name LIKE \'%' + el + '%\'';
    first = false;
}
```

Comment: This does work, but it turns out that you don't even need to include the IN operator - it's implied

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, you don't need to have both LIKE & IN. By setting the return value as a list, and referencing an iterator in the query, IN is implied. This query does both:

```
SELECT id, owner.name FROM Account WHERE name LIKE :entityList
```

See here:
[SOQL: Performing Query with both LIKE & IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443580/soql-performing-query-with-both-like-in/28476910#28476910)

Also, there doesn't seem to be a good way to bulkify the SOSL query